# Compare numbers in a nested file

Tags: list, sorting, vim

Example:

```
let list = [[23, '2'], [2, '3'], [55, '4'], [1, '5']]
```

I'm trying to do a numeric sort of this list (using the 1st field):
list[indexnr][0]

I've found this function in the help files:

```
function! MyCompare(i1, i2)
   return (a:i1 + 0) - (a:i2 + 0)
endfunction
```

How can I adapt it to a nested list to let it work with above example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to give an index to you params:

```
function! MyCompare(i1, i2)
   return a:i1[0] - a:i2[0]
endfunction
```